# Rodar projeto Spring Boot sem Datasource e JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, multi-tenancy

Eu tenho um projeto `Java` com `Spring Boot` que tem que ser `mult-tenacy` e pra isso eu estou tentando usar o `Flyway` para executar o `migrate()` por um endpoint passando os dados necessários para conectar em um banco de dados especifico (`url, username, password`) e para fazer as conexões com o banco de dados estou usando o `JdbcTemplate` e ai que está o problema.

Como o projeto tem que ser `mult-tenacy` (pode se conectar com varios bancos de dados) eu preciso executar o projeto sem um `datasource` configurado (normalmente se configura uma `url, user e password` de um banco no arquivo `application.properties`) e ai que da problema pois ao executar o `auto configuration` do `datasource` e do `JdbcTemplate` o `Spring` da erro `(Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' ou 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your configuration.)`, eu já pesquisei e vi muita gente falando para colocar as classes de `auto configuration` no `exclude` do `@SpringBootApplication`, e mesmo colocando os dois ainda não consigo executar o projeto.

Alguém ai pode me dar uma luz?

edit 1:

aqui esta o código do meu arquivo `application.properties`:

```
server.port=${port:8082}
spring.flyway.enabled=false
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
```

A classe main:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.com.b2code")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class RunAdm extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements 
CommandLineRunner {

    public static final String URL_FRONTEND = "*";


    /**
     * Método main do módulo de Gestão.
     *
     * @param args argumentos de inicialização
     * @throws Exception uma exception genérica
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(RunAdm.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder 
    configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(RunAdm.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

e aqui uma classe que eu uso o `JdbcTemplate`:

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class ClienteQueryRepositoryImpl implements ClienteQueryRepository {

    private final @NonNull
    JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Override
    public List<Cliente> findAll() {
        return jdbc.query(ClienteQuerySQL.SELECT_ALL_CLIENTE_SQL, new ClienteRowMapper());
    }

}
```

Comment: E ai @Bruno, você consegue colocar sua configuração atual do `application.properties` e algum código de como está configurada sua aplicação hoje? (classe onde você está utilizando o JdbcTemplate e a Main da app)

Comment: Vou lhe adiantar um detalhe que talvez ajude, você pode passar um datasource instanciando seu `JdbcTemplate`. Você pode montar o datasource como passei na outra resposta (utilizando `DataSourceBuilder`)

Comment: Link da documentação do [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)

Comment: Opa @nullptr editei a pergunta la e coloquei o código, do jeito q eu instancio o JdbcTemplate eu acho que não da pra passar um datasource, se tivesse alguma forma de criar um Bean para setar o datasource que não executasse quando o projeto da startup, tipo um método que eu chamo e passo os parâmetros(url, senha e usuario) pra ele criar o datasource principal ae o JdbcTemplate usaria este datasource...

(ah e desculpe pela demora para responder )

Comment: Você poderia ter uma classe abstrata para seus repositórios que recebe como parâmetros o user, password e url, e utilizar a mesma estratégia que usei no *wrapper* do flyway, e criar um `new JdbcTemplate(datasource)`, sem realizar injeção

Comment: @nullptr baah cara, eu acho que isso não é muito viável pra mim, mas assim o que eu quero mesmo é poder setar o `datasource` em tempo real, pq normalmente ele é setado no startup do projeto(o Spring tem a `autoconfiguration` que faz isso automaticamente precisando apenas que coloque as propriedades do banco no arquivo `application.properties` mas também da pra fazer um `Bean` que retorna um `DataSource` que ele faz a mesma coisa)

Comment: Eu ja consegui fazer o projeto executar com um `datasource` "vazio" só que não sei como fazer, por exemplo, que certo endpoint com parâmetros para a conexão com o banco de dados (url, username e password) execute um Bean ou um método que use esses parâmetros e seta o `datasource`

Comment: Não entendi o não viável, voce vai montar o datasource em runtime, nao é exatamente o que você quer?

Comment: @nullptr poderia me dar um exemplo dessa ideia de criar uma classe abstrata pros meus `respositorys` com os parâmetros pra conectar com o banco (url, user, password) e tals... ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94359/discussion-between-nullptr-and-bruno-eduardo).